# Android APP Null Pointer Exception ApplicationInfo

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

When I run my application I'm getting a NULL Pointer exception.  I know where it is I'm just not quite sure how to solve it.  Is this because the class is protected?  I'm not sure what i'm missing here any help would be greatly appreciated.  thanks.

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference

```
public class IperfTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

Context context;


@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    // StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Process process = null;
    String appFileDir = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/files";
    // String appFileDir ="/data/data/com.netscout.iperf3_client/files";
    System.out.print(appFileDir);
    String commandLine = appFileDir + "/iperf3.5mod";
    String args1 = "-c10.0.150.117";
    String args2 = "-c129.196.197.116";


    try {
        //The process is now being run with the verified parameters.
        process = new ProcessBuilder(commandLine, args1, "-J", "-O3", "P2")
                .redirectErrorStream(true)
                .start();

        // A buffered output of the stdout is being initialized so the
        // iPerf3 output could be displayed on the screen.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                (process.getInputStream()));
        int read;

        //The output text is accumulated into a string buffer and
        // published to the GUI
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.append(buffer, 0, read);
            Log.v("OUTPUT", String.valueOf(output));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("IO Exception:", String.valueOf(e));
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: "Is this because the class is protected?" - It's because you never assign the `context` field a valid reference before you try to use it in `doInBackground()`.

Comment: make a constructor in the async task and initialise the context in the constructor